# Get internationalized label text without the label tag wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The `FormBuilder#label` method ([see docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label)) returns a `<label>` tag for the given attribute. If the user does not supply text for the label, the i18n library is used to do a lookup. The order of the checks is:

1. `helpers.label.object.method`
2. `object.class.human_attribute_name(method_name)`
3. `method_name.humanize`

Is there an API method anywhere that performs a similar lookup but does NOT wrap the output in a `<label>` tag? If not, what's the best way to strip the `<label>` tag from the tag returned by `FormBuilder#label` without stripping any OTHER html tags that the internationalized string might contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I have the following code which does the brute force stripping of the label tags. Looking for better solutions...

`label(attribute,text).gsub(/^<label(.*?)>/,'').gsub(/<\/label>$/,'')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Class.human_attribute_name(attribute)`, ex:

```
Person.human_attribute_name("first_name") # => "First name"
# you can also use :first_name
```

[Source](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name)

Comment: That's only accurate if you want to use the attribute name as the label.